# Symfonys Autoloader - Implement Parent Namespaces

Tags: php, class, symfony, namespaces, autoloader

I am using Symfonys Autoloader for a project having the following folder/class structure:

```
App
+- Package1
|
+- Package2
  +- Class1.php
|
- Interface1.php
```

How do i implement a class from a parent namespace now.
Like `Interface1` from `Class1` for example.
This does not work:

```
namespace App\Package1

Class1 implements App\Interface1
{
    //implement some functions here...
}
```

The Autoloader trys to include `App\Package2\Class1\App\Interface1` then.

Best regards,

Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the symfony's classloader works great:)

In this case, it's a php syntax problem.

You need to import the namespace with "use" or more easily you just need a backslash in front of the classname

for example:

```
namespace App\Package1;

use App\Interface1;

Class1 implements Interface1
{
    //implement some functions here...
}
```

or

```
namespace App\Package1;

Class1 implements \App\Interface1;
{
    //implement some functions here...
}
```